# Bootstrap method of Kaiser Guttman in R

Tags: r

I would like some help. I want to code the "bootstrap" function in R using the eigenvalues from my principal component analysis (PCA) to obtain confidence intervals and be able to apply the bootstrap Kaiser-Guttman method. Here is the code I have started, but I am having trouble coding the "ouss" function correctly.

```
library(bootstrap)

x=acp$eig[,1]

perc95 = function(x) quantile(x,.95)

h=bootstrap(x,50,ouss,func=perc95)
```